# How does one construct $\omega + \omega$ in ZFC?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I can't figure out what axioms allow me to construct it.  Most of the answers I've encountered say to define $f(x,y) := y = \omega + x$ and use Replacement, but I don't see how that would work.  $+$ requires a recursive definition, and each instance of Replacement will use a fixed wff, so I can't encode recursion that way.

I'm looking for a specific sequence of axioms in ZFC I can apply which will prove the existence of the set $\omega + \omega$.

We have ω by using Specification on Infinity with a class function that says it has all sets which are in all inductive functions.  We have $\omega + k$ for some arbitrary $k$ by taking successor, $x \cup \{x\}$, with itself $k$ times.  Can't figure out how to get beyond that.

Comment: Do you know how to construct $\omega$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @jjagmath yeah, use Specification with a proposition that every member is a member of every inductive set on Infinity.

Comment: That and any other things you have done or tried should be in your question. Don't wait to people to ask for it.

Comment: The expression $y=\omega+x$ is equivalent to “$y$ is an ordinal and there is an order-preserving bijection between $x$ and the elements of $y$ greater than $\omega$.” This is a fixed wff.

Comment: For another approach, there's also a fixed wff $g(x,y)$ denoting “$y$ is of the form $\{(\alpha,\omega+\alpha):\alpha\le x\}$,” which would resemble the recursive definition of $+$ more closely. $f(x,y)$ could then be defined in terms of $g(x,y)$, or in terms of the set constructed by $g(x,y)$.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger For the former, how would one define a bijection as a wff?  For the latter, how does one encode recursion in ZFC?  I'm trying to be as low level as possible.

Comment: A bijection is a type of function, and a function is a type of set. Specifically, a bijection is a set of ordered pairs such that each first component and each last component shows up only once.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger I know what a bijection is, I don't know how to frame it in first order logic for an infinite set.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Your comment(s), at least the first one, could be edited as an answer.

Comment: An overkill method would be to apply Mostowski collapse on the well-ordered set of $2 \times \omega$ with lexicographic product ordering.

Answer (score 1):

I talked to a buddy of mine who managed to get a formula figured out.  It's a doozy.  Can define a function x -> $\omega + x$ in the following way.

Let <x,y> be ordered pair {{x}, {x,y}}, g(x) denote the unique value y such that <x,y> $\in$ a set function g, Im g all k such that <x, k> $\in g$

f(x,y,A) := (g is a set function x -> y) $ \land (\omega = y - Im\ g)\ \land\ \forall m \in x(\forall v(v \in g(m) \iff (v \in \omega\ \lor\ \exists u \in m (v = g(u)))))$

Then, with domain $\mathbb{N}$, we use with with Replacement and should get $\omega + \omega$.

The actual sets g that the formula generates don't matter, but the first few are:

$F(0, \omega, \mathbb{N}) \to g = \{\}$

$F(1, \omega+1, \mathbb{N}) \to g = \{<0, \omega>\}$

$F(2, \omega+2, \mathbb{N}) \to g = \{<0, \omega>, <1, \omega + 1>\}$

Answer (score -2):

You've mentioned that we can construct $\omega + k$ as a successor ordinal, which is true for some natural number $k$, but this approach doesn't work for $\omega + \omega$. However, this is still useful, as we can think of $\omega + \omega$ as exactly the least such ordinal which is not $\omega$ or a successor ordinal.

Using first order logic, we can describe the necessary conditions like 'being a successor' to construct $\omega + \omega$.